# On the continuity of a function on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function on $\mathbb R^2$ with $f(0,0)=0.$ If,

(1) for any $k\in \mathbb R$, $\lim_{x\to0}f(x,kx)=0$,

(2) $\lim_{y\to0}f(0,y)=0$.

then, is it true that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, no. A standard counter-example is
$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0 & \text{ if } (x,y)=(0,0) \\ \dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} & \text{ if } (x,y)\not=(0,0) \end{array}\right.$$
$f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ since $f(y^2,y)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ for every $y\not=0$ while $f(0,0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider $$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1,&y\geq\sqrt{|x|},\,x\neq0\\0,&\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x.$ For $k\ne 0$ let  $f(x,kx)=x/k.$  For $n\in \mathbb N$ let $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n, 1/n^2).$ Now for any $r>0$ we have $$0<y_n<x_n<r \land f(x_n,y_n)=1$$ for all sufficiently large $n\in \mathbb N.$

Equivalently let $f(x,y)=x^2/y$ for $y\ne 0,$ and $f(x,0)=0.$

Remarks:This is similar to the concept of uniform convergence: For functions $g,h$ from $D\subset \mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R,$ let $$\|g-h\|_D=\min (1, \sup \{|g(x)-h(x)|:x\in D\}).$$ If $g(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n(x)$ for each $x\in D,$ for a sequence  $(g_n:D \to \mathbb R)_{n\in \mathbb N},$ we say the convergence is uniform iff $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\|g-g_n\|_D=0.$$ If the convergence  is uniform and each $g_n$ is continuous on $D,$ then $g$ will also be continuous on $D.$ But if the convergence is not uniform then $g$ may fail to be continuous on $D.$

For example let $D=[0,1]$ and $g_n(x)=x^n.$

For this $Q$, with $D=\mathbb R$, it suffices that  $f(x,x/n)=g_n(x)$  for  $n\in \mathbb N$, where $\lim_{x\to 0}g_n(x)=0$ for each $n,$ but that  for any $r>0$ there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ and $x$ such that   $|x|<r$ and $|g_n(x)|=1.$